# Oracle PIVOT issue (NULL pivot columns in result)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, pivot

I've got weird issue with Oracle, while I try do PIVOT. Basically it return NULL for all pivoted columns while it shouldn't

```
WITH 
    "Customer" AS (
        SELECT * FROM "doCustomer" WHERE __some_conditions_here__
    )
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    "Customer"
PIVOT (
    MIN("ChargeCommission")   AS "ChargeCommission"
    FOR ("Index") IN (
        01 AS C01, 02 AS C02, 03 AS C03, 04 AS C04, 05 AS C05, 06 AS C06, 07 AS C07, 08 AS C08, 09 AS C09, 10 AS C10,
        11 AS C11, 12 AS C12, 13 AS C13, 14 AS C14, 15 AS C15, 16 AS C16, 17 AS C17, 18 AS C18, 19 AS C19, 20 AS C20
    )
)
```

"Customer" always return not null data, so it's not problem with the data.
But result of whole query depends on what I enter in the some_conditions_here. I've found dependence - less data in "Customer" -> less nulls.
I know that I can rewrite this query that way it'll use decode/group by, but I'm just curious why it behaves like that.
Version of Oracle is 11g.

Comment: Is "Index" a character or numeric field?

Comment: @MarkBannister - Numeric; I've found another fun fact - if I enumerate less than 20 numbers (10 for example) in the FOR("Index") the result is also correct.

Answer (score -1):

```
<FOR ("Index") IN (
    01 AS C01, 02 AS C02, 03 AS C03, 04 AS C04, 05 AS C05, 06 AS C06, 07 AS C07, 08 AS C08, 09 AS C09, 10 AS C10,
    11 AS C11, 12 AS C12, 13 AS C13, 14 AS C14, 15 AS C15, 16 AS C16, 17 AS C17, 18 AS C18, 19 AS C19, 20 AS C20
)>
```

Try this, without using aliases ... it should work